# Dynamic IP Notification Using Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This script is very basic: it does one thing. Connect to it's root and it will log your IP if it has never seen it before. Connect to `/logs`, and it will show a list of unique IPs within the server storage. I can't take 100 percent credit for it. I grabbed it off of Stack Overflow, modified it to actually run on App Engine, and changed the save mechanism to prevent duplicate entries. This thing is so simple it's shocking; considering how many different super-elaborate ways I can waste money and time doing the same thing. I use it to keep track of my `ssh` IP. I run `wget` on my `App Engine` address every ten minutes. Can this be improved? Are there any flaws which may compromise its efficiency?

**helloworld.py**

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Log(db.Model):
    access_time = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    ip_address = db.StringProperty()
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ip = self.request.remote_addr
        log = Log()
        logs = Log.all()
        is_new = True
        for log in logs:
                if ip == log: is_new = False
        if is_new:
                log.ip_address = ip
                log.put()
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Logged your visit from ip address %s' % ip)
class LogPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        logs = Log.all()

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Ip addresses: ')
        for log in logs:
            self.response.out.write(log.ip_address + ',')
app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage), ('/logs', LogPage)],
                                     debug=True)
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app
```

P.S. I'm pretty sure this isn't violating any contracts or agreements. Tell me if I'm wrong about that.

**Credit: [Get IP address in Google App Engine + Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231077/get-ip-address-in-google-app-engine-python)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Lint

PEP 8 recommends [two blank lines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines) around class definitions.  Indentation should be [consistently 4 spaces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) — an important convention in Python, where indentation matters a lot.

`log = Log()` is pointless.

### Database

A more Pythonic way to write this…

> ```
> logs = Log.all()
> is_new = True
> for log in logs:
>         if ip == log: is_new = False
> ```

… would be `is_new = ip not in Log.all()`.

But your code wouldn't even work, since an IP address would never be equal to a `db.Model` object!

It also doesn't scale well, since it doesn't take advantage of the [datastore's capabilities](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries).  You should be using a query like this:

```
Logs.all().filter('ip_address =', ip).run(limit=1)
```